# If a user modifies a value, change it in real time on all the apps

Tags: android, ios

This is just a question regarding the concept so I'm not looking on code snippets or something similar because I'm not a programmer but rather...let's say the product owner so I need to know what it takes to achieve this before talking with the developers (which I need to find first).

So here it is: I am thinking on creating an app compatible both with iOS and Android which (amongst other things) will display a value with the following characteristics:

1. This value will be visible to all the users that are running the app
2. If a user clicks on a particular button, the value is incremented.
3. If the value is incremented, all other users will see the new value in real time.
4. The value can be changed thousands of time per second, deepening on how many users are clicking the button.

Again, I'm mainly interested in the concept so any suggestion will be appreciated. For example since the value will get updated so many times per second, how do I store/modify it? Or how can I push it so fast to all the apps?

Comment: You'd have to have a server which handles connections to all the clients, and additionally handles the "increment" when the button is clicked. Updates in real time can be done with websockets.

Comment: Exactly what I just replied below. I think this is a viable solution however I need to find out which is the best way to do it and not crash the system while getting thousands of updates.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need `Push Notifications` in your App.

The Android version of this is [Google Cloud Messaging](https://developer.android.com/google/gcm/index.html).

The iOS version is [Apple Push Notification Service](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/Chapters/ApplePushService.html).

All Android devices maintain a connection with Google, through this one connection all other Apps that use GCM can be messaged. Your server sends a message to Google, and Google transmits that message to the IDs of the devices you wish to receive the message (in your case, all of them).

Comment: _"The value can be changed thousands of time per second"_, _"in your case, all of them_". With hundreds of users and thousands of updates per second, Google won't like that.

Comment: That is true, I missed that when I read the question. @BogdanR: As JonasCz writes, Google will be upset if you do that so often. It might be that you need a custom server to handle that.

Comment: Or what if I'm using a server that will store and constantly update the value and client (user app) connects to it when it opens. So instead of constantly pushing the new value to all the apps, the value will be accessible from a single location and pulled every time the user is in that particular screen. I don't know if it makes sense.

Answer (score 1):

You could open a socket to your server with each user and send data from your server to all open sockets on the server. Sockets should be opened and kept alive in a bound service, which gets destroyed once the user terminates the app.

Just make simple communication protocol and then implement it on iOS and Android. Note the delays due ping and stuff.